# What is the kusama block production reward distribution mechanism?

Tags: kusama, pallet-treasury, rewards

I am writing a custom pallet for distribution of rewards to different stake holders. The idea is to distribute block production reward in the stakeholders of my system and a portion it will go to the treasury.

I wanted to know the kusama mechanisim/pallet/code for distribution of reward to get an idea? Can any one please point me to the exact pallet in the kusama code base that is responsible for distribution of block reward on kusama network.

Answer (score 2):

Basically,

1. A validator produces a block and then rewards him with 20 points https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/8186c519a861ea519ed3dc4391f6e13f64300ce6/frame/staking/src/pallet/impls.rs#L1225
2. Compute total payout here https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/8186c519a861ea519ed3dc4391f6e13f64300ce6/frame/staking/src/lib.rs#L850
3. Distribute the reward base on the points here https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/8186c519a861ea519ed3dc4391f6e13f64300ce6/frame/staking/src/pallet/impls.rs#L192-L194